# OneHotEncoding raises IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding, index-error

I have a dataframe named `data` that has the below given properties:

> ```
> [880 rows x 10 columns]
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> MultiIndex: 880 entries, (123, 456) to (789, 890)
> Data columns (total 10 columns):
> Date_Diff            880 non-null float64
> Response             880 non-null category
> Len1                 880 non-null int64
> Type1                877 non-null category
> Len2                 880 non-null int64
> Type2                880 non-null category
> Len_Diff             880 non-null int64
> Same_Institution     880 non-null category
> Same_Type            880 non-null category
> Score                880 non-null float64
> dtypes: category(5), float64(2), int64(3)
> memory usage: 82.0+ KB
> None
> ```

*Note: The indices on the dataframe are string columns called ID1 and ID2. This is how I set the multiindex: `data = data.set_index(['ID1','ID2'], drop = True)`. Since `drop = True`, you won't see them in the above dataframe.*

I am trying to encode the categorical variables `Type1` and `Type2` using `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`. This is my code:

```
# Encoding function
def encode(data):
    global cat_columns
    cat_columns = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['category','object']))
    le = LabelEncoder()
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = cat_columns)
    for col in cat_columns:
        data[col] = le.fit_transform(data[col])
    data = ohe.fit_transform(data)
    return data

# Use encoding function
encode(data)
```

I get an `IndexError` when I run this code. The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-xxx> in <module>()
     14     return data
     15 
---> 16 encode(data)

<ipython-input-xxx> in encode(data)
---> 13     data = ohe.fit_transform(data)
     14     return data
     15 

/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y)
   1900         """
   1901         return _transform_selected(X, self._fit_transform,
-> 1902                                    self.categorical_features, copy=True)
   1903 
   1904     def _transform(self, X):

/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.pyc in _transform_selected(X, transform, selected, copy)
   1706     ind = np.arange(n_features)
   1707     sel = np.zeros(n_features, dtype=bool)
-> 1708     sel[np.asarray(selected)] = True
   1709     not_sel = np.logical_not(sel)
   1710     n_selected = np.sum(sel)

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

What is causing this error? 
 I tried removing IDs as indices and tried, still throws the same error.

> **EDIT:** Adding a subset of the dataframe here: Run the html snippet to see it as a table. 
>  *Some of the columns' data types have been
>   changed since. The data types are updated in the dataframe properties
>   above.*
>   *`Response` is the target variable and is categorical.*
>   *`Same_Institution` and `Same_Type` have been changed from integers to  categorical binary variables*
>   *`Type1` and `Type2` have been changed from pandas objects to categories*

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID1</th><th>ID2</th><th>Len1</th><th>Type1</th><th>Len2</th><th>Type2</th><th>Len_Diff</th><th>Date_Diff</th><th>Same_Institution</th><th>Same_Type</th><th>Score</th><th>Response</th></tr><tr><td>121</td><td>977</td><td>10185</td><td>PR</td><td>10185</td><td>MR</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>214</td><td>753</td><td>5039</td><td>MR</td><td>4926</td><td>MR</td><td>113</td><td>9.266666667</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0.997031978</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>378</td><td>919</td><td>45404</td><td>PR</td><td>45404</td><td>PR</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>283</td><td>685</td><td>821076</td><td>40-F</td><td>412353</td><td>AR</td><td>408723</td><td>0.35</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.888266653</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>452</td><td>837</td><td>16343</td><td>PR</td><td>16343</td><td>PR</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>333</td><td>726</td><td>22204</td><td>PR</td><td>20897</td><td>6-K</td><td>1307</td><td>11.3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.99251128</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>107</td><td>960</td><td>9781</td><td>6-K</td><td>6073</td><td>MR</td><td>3708</td><td>0.483333333</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.933646747</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>236</td><td>768</td><td>3375</td><td>PR</td><td>2945</td><td>MR</td><td>430</td><td>46.58333333</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.239269675</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>419</td><td>829</td><td>81247</td><td>MR</td><td>81247</td><td>MR</td><td>0</td><td>0.016666667</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>184</td><td>991</td><td>51474</td><td>PR</td><td>51474</td><td>ER</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>217</td><td>868</td><td>23714</td><td>ER</td><td>26633</td><td>8-K</td><td>2919</td><td>1.716666667</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.980611207</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>202</td><td>622</td><td>4638</td><td>MR</td><td>4638</td><td>PR</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>308</td><td>883</td><td>73476</td><td>ER</td><td>404584</td><td>6-K</td><td>331108</td><td>12.58333333</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.825482503</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>186</td><td>880</td><td>291279</td><td>FIN SUPP</td><td>320893</td><td>6-K</td><td>29614</td><td>4.483333333</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.991668299</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>305</td><td>896</td><td>22988</td><td>PR</td><td>28554</td><td>6-K</td><td>5566</td><td>22.1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.941192693</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Just wondering.. have you looked at [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)?

Comment: as @ Scratch'N'Purr mentioned get_dummies of pandas may be able to do this without dealing with sklearn. Also, if you can add a small subset of data that can reproduce the error it could be much easier for people to answer.

Comment: Can you post a small part of your data on which this error is occuring, and the way you make the dataFrame?

Comment: Added a piece of the dataset to the question.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, `get_dummies` works fine btw. Just wanted to try `OneHotEncoder`

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the exact same error with OneHotEncoder.

Core issue is that the *categorical_features* parameter doesn't handle named columns. From OneHotEncoder documentation:

```
categorical_features : "all" or array of indices or mask
    Specify what features are treated as categorical.

    - 'all' (default): All features are treated as categorical.
    - array of indices: Array of categorical feature indices.
    - mask: Array of length n_features and with dtype=bool.
```

What worked for me was to generate a boolean mask first using a snippet like:

```
cat_columns = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['category','object']))
column_mask = []
for column_name in list(data.columns.values):
    column_mask.append(column_name in cat_columns)

# And then pass the column_mask into the OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = column_mask)
```

So your original function would be:

```
# Encoding function
def encode(data):
    global cat_columns
    cat_columns = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['category','object']))
    column_mask = []
    for column_name in list(data.columns.values):
        column_mask.append(column_name in cat_columns)
    le = LabelEncoder()
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = column_mask)
    for col in cat_columns:
        data[col] = le.fit_transform(data[col])
    data = ohe.fit_transform(data)
    return data

# Use encoding function
encode(data)
```